# Conduction between charged spheres

Tags: electrostatics

When 2 bodies ( spheres)are bought in contact with each other ( one charged and other uncharged ) , what will happen ? , I mean , how much of the charge will get distributed and how to determine that . Also , in cases where a charged shell is placed inside a spherical uncharged conductors, the uncharged shell will get a negative charge on the inner surface , and a positive charge on the outer ( assuming inner sphere is + charged), so will the electric field , electric potential, electric potential energy and flux get affected by the outer sphere( asking this since the outer sphere will have net charge 0 right ? )